# php - Удаление повторяющихся строк

Tags: php

На хостинге есть файл представляющий собой форму:

```
abc | Text | Text
cba | Text | Text
cba | Text | Text
```

Сравнивать нужно только первый столбец. И вопрос заключается, как можно сделать удаление повторно строк, в которых совпадают первые столбцы?

Comment: Ну я думаю тебе помогут "регулярные выражения" вот на пример это [ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов:

```
$fn = 'file_name.txt'; // имя текст.файла

$arr = file_exists($fn) ? file($fn, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) : [];

if (! empty($arr)) {
    $tmp = [];
    $arr = array_filter($arr, function($i)use(&$tmp){
        return (in_array(($e = explode('|', $i)[0]), $tmp)) ? '' : $tmp[] = $e;
    });
    file_put_contents($fn, join("\n", $arr));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$inFile = fopen('myfile', 'r');
if ($inFile) {
  $outFile = fopen('myfile.tmp', 'wb');
  if ($outFile) {
    $keys = [];
    while (!feof($inFile)) {
      $str = fgets($inFile);
      $strData = explode(' | ', $str);
      if (!isset($keys[$strData[0]])) {
        fwrite($outFile, $str . PHP_EOL);
        $keys[] = $strData[0];
      }
    }
    fclose($outFile);
  }
  fclose($inFile);
  rename('myfile.tmp', 'myfile');
}
```